# updating UI without blocking UI from User interaction in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I an implementing an IDE based on XCode design. It has been a lot of learning.

I need to update UI without blocking it.

I already have a pair of threads 
using Grand Central Dispatch.
Basically I have an Interpreter, and an UI with an codeView (NSTextView) and an outputView (NSTextView). When I press play/run the IDE runs the code. It launches two threads, both with an while loop. One to run the program, the other to update the UI from any output or message sent from interpreter.

Something like this:

```
// program execution thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
        {
            self.interpreter_s.execute()
        });
    // update UI while interpreter thread is running
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        {
            self.updateUIWhileInterpreterRunningThread()
        });
}
```

They both communicate one with the other, so they have concurrency.

According with the research I've made, it's recommended to update the UI using the main_queue(). However, when I do this, *it blocks the UI from receiving user input.*

In my case, *this causes the stop button to be rendered  useless.*

So I need an way to update the UI from the updates from interpreter thread without blocking the Views from user input.
Any thoughts?

I have huge preference from an solution already using Grand Central Dispatch.  I also want to avoid dispatching UI Updates from the interpreter thread, since this could be terribly inefficient in this particular case.

Comment: The UI effectively "resides" on the main thread and thus you must make UI updates on the main thread. However I am not surprised that running a while loop on the main thread blocks user interaction. Perhaps you could run the while-loop on a different thread, and then any time that a UI update is actually needed, which wouldn't be throughout the entirety of the while-loop, you could pop back to the main queue and maker the UI update.

Comment: It was harder than I expected to handle this extra concurrency, but it worked fine. 


Thank you!